# Extend CrudRepository interfaces into base interface

Tags: java, interface, spring-data-jpa

How to extend interfaces `CrudRepository<T, ID>`, `MongoRepository<T, ID>`, `PagingAndSortingRepository<T, ID>` into `BaseRepository<T, ID>`? (if possible)

I want to have access methods of three interfaces.

I've tried:

```
@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
public interface BaseRepositoryDao<T, ID> extends CrudRepository,
        MongoRepository, PagingAndSortingRepository {

}
```

How can I achieve that?

**EDIT:**

`MongoRepository` already extends `PagingAndSortingRepository`

Comment: So what's the quesiton?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [`MongoRepostory`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/repository/MongoRepository.html) *is a* `CrudRepository` and a `PagingAndSortingRepository` so the following is sufficient:

```
public interface BaseRepositoryDao<T, ID extends Serializable> extends MongoRepository<T, ID> {

}
```

Comment: How is this different from my answer?

Comment: @bot you answer _was_ very wrong. And still is slightly wrong, as it misses the type constraint.

Comment: I guess I could be wrong but could you elaborate on what type parameter does it miss?

Comment: @bot `ID` in `MongoRespository` is required to `extends Serializable` so a generic `interface` that `extends MongoRespository` is required to have the same type constraint on `ID`.

Comment: I was not aware of such a restriction. In that case, I do stand corrected.

Comment: @bot it says it in the docs you linked in your own answer. It comes from the type restrictions on the base [`interface Repository`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/Repository.html)

Comment: Yes. I saw that but assumed that it was okay to not have the same restriction when extending the interface. Like I said, I do stand corrected. I assume it would be a compilation error then?